# Is Unix find overwhelmed by multiple prunes and type f?

Tags: find

I have spent days on this Rubik's cube. Anything I do to fix one problem breaks another.

I am on POSIX compliant MacOS X 10.5 thru 10.14.  I am calling this from a Perl script in a context of

```
  system ("find blah blah > FILENAME");
```

I need Unix 'find' to do all these things at once.

- start at a volume root e.g. `/Volumes/My HD`
- do not cross file systems
- print files only, not directories or symlinks
- do not even descend into *multiple* directories like `net dev system`.  (I.e. do not explore /Volumes/foo/dev/ but do explore /Volumes/foo/Users/Jim/**dev**/github/twonky/)
- the start point may contain spaces

Right now I am doing the following: (broken into several lines for readability; it's actually one long line)

```
 Find -x '/Volumes/foo/' 
    -path '/Volumes/foo//dev/*' -prune
    -path '/Volumes/foo//net/*' -prune
    -path '/Volumes/foo//system/*' -prune
    -o -type f -print
```

The reason for the double / is *find*’s printout includes the // because the starting point ends in a /.  The Prune paths must agree, or they won't match.  Why does the starting point end in /? Because if it doesn't, *find* fails on any starting point with a space in the name, like "My HD". Tried that.

Right now, find is only excludes the first directory in the list.  The rest, it just ignores.  I am currently testing on OS X 10.5 but I need something that works everywhere.

Is multiple prunes + files only + spaces in filenames a bridge too far? Am I just asking too much of *find*?

Comment: " I am calling this from a Perl script " Do not call `find` from Perl code. You have everything you need inside Perl already, like at `File::Find` module which is in Perl core, or whatever wrapper on it like `File::Find::Rule`.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek probably because this thing started as 2 lines of perl around a 'find' and slowly evolved into 200 lines of Perl... you know how it goes. I'll look at those options ...a "touch the high points" answer on how to do each of my requirements with F:F:R would definitely get an upvote from me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer with a pure Perl solution.

With this sandbox:

```
$ tree -F Volumes/ 
Volumes/ 
└── My\ HD/
    ├── Users/
    │   └── Jim/
    │       └── dev/
    │           └── github/
    │               └── twonky/
    │                   └── i_there.txt
    ├── dev/
    ├── net/
    ├── start.bat
    └── system/
        └── hello

9 directories, 3 files
```

The following Perl code using `File::Find`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use File::Find;

my $start = 'Volumes/My HD';
my $start_dev = (stat($start))[0];
my @exclude = qw/net dev system/;
my %skipdir;

sub wanted {
    my $name = $_;
    return if (stat($name))[0] != $start_dev;
    $skipdir{$File::Find::name} = 1 if $File::Find::dir eq $start && grep { $name eq $_ } @exclude;
    if (exists($skipdir{$File::Find::dir})) {
        $skipdir{$File::Find::name} = 1 if -d $name;
        return;
    }
    return if ! -f $name;
    say "Got: $File::Find::name";

}

my %args = (
    wanted => \&wanted,
    follow => 1,
    follow_skip => 1,
);


find(\%args, $start);
```

gives the expected (if I understood you right):

```
Got: Volumes/My HD/start.bat
Got: Volumes/My HD/Users/Jim/dev/github/twonky/i_there.txt
```

It is a POC, it can be enhanced.

Note also that you have the `find2perl` tool that is documented to be able to convert a specific `find` invocation to the associate Perl code using `File::Find` with the same criteria.

Now with `Path::Class` the code may seem simpler/easier to read (for the same result):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Path::Class;

my $start = Path::Class::Dir->new('Volumes/My HD');
my @exclude = qw/net dev system/;

$start->recurse(callback => sub {
    my $node = shift;
    if ($node->is_dir) {
        return $node->PRUNE if $node->parent eq $start && grep { $node->dir_list(-1) eq $_ } @exclude;
        return;
    }
    return $node->PRUNE if $node->stat()->dev != $start->stat()->dev;
    say 'Got: ', $node->stringify();
}, preorder => 1)
```

Comment: I didn't *quite* go your way, but staying in perl was definitely the way to go. I'll score a mental note to familiarize myself with File::Find.

Answer (score 5):

You need an "or" to accomplish the second match -- no single path will match both `-path '/Volumes/foo//dev/*'` and `-path '/Volumes/foo//net/*'`

```
Find -x '/Volumes/foo/' 
    \( -path '/Volumes/foo//dev/*' 
    -o -path '/Volumes/foo//net/*' 
    -o -path '/Volumes/foo//system/*' \) -prune
-o -type f -print
```

Comment: It's very unexpected because a prune is a "warn-off", it's an exclusion, I can't have find iterate into those directories. You wouldn't figure and/or would apply to them.

Comment: This was very helpful, it got me through a month and a half lol.

Answer (score 1):

With your help, I was able to stabilize "find".  However moving the code from OS X 10.5 to 10.10 *broke it again*. That was the last straw.  'find' is simply too obtuse, underdocumented and inconsistent, and it's a unix core feature for Pete's sake!  This. This is why I hate other people's code.  I started to hunker down to learn File::Find, then thought "what am I *doing?  I can code this myself* in 20 minutes".

Which I summarily did.

```
sub iterate {
  my ($mydir, $ref_FH, $homevol, $ref_excludes) = @_;  # last is ref to hash

  return if (defined ($ref_excludes -> {$mydir}));   # No excludes

  my $thisvol = (stat($mydir))[0];    # What's my volume?
  return if ($thisvol != $homevol) ;  # No crossing volumes

  opendir (my $DIR, $mydir);
  while (defined (my $file = readdir($DIR))) {
    next if ($file eq '.' or $file eq '..');
    my $full = "$mydir/$file";   

    if (-l $full) {                                   # symlink
                                                         # nope
    } elsif (-f $full) {                              # file
      print {$$ref_FH} "$full\n";                        # print it
    } elsif (-d $full) {                              # dir
      &iterate($full, $ref_FH, $homevol, $ref_excludes); # iterate
    }
  }
}
```

And it's fast.  And light - this code is half the size (and more maintainable) than the code that formatted "find"'s arg list!